# vsts project collection administrator remove

Tags: azure-devops

I accidentally deleted all users of project collection administrator. I am the owner, but I have been deleted as well so I can no longer add users, delete permission groups, create projects, or change the owner to someone else.
What should I do?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to raise a support ticket :-(

Comment: Do you mean delete the **Project Administrators** group? VSTS will deny you to delete this group (https://imgur.com/a/YQuLn). If you deleted other group, you can create a new to replace.

Comment: Use the Administration Console to access those groups and re-add yourself